# How to take only one element from the emoji string?

Tags: c#, string, emoji

For example, I have such a string and I only need the house emoji.

Comment: do you mean the second character in the string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use StringInfo class to get the house as follows with 1 for the position and 1 for the number of elements

```
string emojiString = "";
StringInfo stringInfo = new StringInfo(emojiString);
string secondEmoji = stringInfo.SubstringByTextElements(1, 1);
```